# Capturing Variables Used in Random Forest

Tags: r

I am running a bagged, random forest model and I am having trouble capturing the predictors used in each tree. I have a total of 34 predictor variables and I'm trying to run a tree model with 4 of those predictor variables.  For each tree model produced I would like to capture the predictor variables and save them to the item called "lstVariableUsed."

I am having problems with the line "lstVariablesUsed <- rbind(lstVariablesUsed, varUsed(model.bagged))."

I have tried numerous ways in which to capture this including varUsed, model.bagged$terms, Name(), and attr(), but am having no luck getting the 4 variables used in each tree. Any help is appreciated.

```
set.seed(1)

lstVariablesUsed <- character()

maxnumpred <- 4
maxnumtrees <- 14


for(numpreds in 1:maxnumpred){
  for(numtrees in 1:maxnumtrees){

    train <- sample(1:nrow(df.FinalClass), nrow(df.FinalClass)/2) 
    FinalClass.test2 = df.FinalClass[-train,]
    DidRetain.test2 = DidRetain[-train]

    model.bagged <- randomForest(DidRetain~., 
                             data=df.FinalClass, 
                             subset=train, 
                             mtry=maxnumpred,
                             ntree=maxnumtrees,
                             importance = FALSE)

    pred.vals.tree <- predict(model.bagged, FinalClass.test2, type="class")
    t <- table(pred.vals.tree, DidRetain.test2)

    acc.val <- (sum(diag(t))/sum(t))*100

    #store the accuracy value in the lstAccuraccy's
    lstAccuracy <- rbind(lstAccuracy, acc.val) 

    #store the variables used in the model
    lstVariablesUsed <- rbind(lstVariablesUsed, varUsed(model.bagged))

    #output the number of iterations of for loop that have passed
    print(paste("     Processed trees: ", numtrees))
  }
#output the number of iterations of for loop that have passed
print(paste("Processed predictors: ", numpreds))
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. `varUsed` gives you a global count of the times that each of the variables in your formula is used. Since your formula is `DidRetain~.`, it will give you a column for each of the variables in your `df`. Is this not what you need?

Comment: From my understanding of the bagged model. It runs multiple times, improving the model each time. The final model (in this case tree number 14) would contain the best model with the best variables. I'd like to capture the exact 4 variables used in every model, but more specifically the last model. The varUsed gives me a tally for all 14 trees, but doesn't tell me which variables were used in the last tree.

Comment: In your code you are using randomForests, which does not work as you are describing. Random Forests fits a lot of trees (in your case only 14, I had not noticed that, a usual number is around hundreds) but using only a limited number of the available variables (that you set with mtry).... Random Forests was actually conceived as an improvement over bagging. Bagging fits many trees over bootstrapped versions of your training data, and again you get many trees and average the results. But no, the last tree is as good as the others.

Comment: So, I originally ran this model with 500 trees and all 34 variables. It then told me that the best model was that of 14 trees and 4 variables. I then modified the code to include 14 trees & 4 variables and re-ran the model. 

If I understand what you are saying, I should just be able to get rid of all the other code and and just run the following:

model.bagged <- randomForest(DidRetain~.,  data=df.FinalClass,  subset=train, mtry=4, ntree=14, importance = FALSE). 


Then I can look at varUsed and the variables with most counts are variables that should be used. Right?

Comment: Sorry, how did you get to the conclusion "the best model was that of 14 trees and 4 variables"? The only parameters that you should fix are the ones you are actually looping in your code: mtry, important to optimize to a value that is optimal and does not overfit, and number of trees, which is somewhat less important, since even if the value is too big it will not overfit. I'd suggest you to take a look to [this book](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/). The theoretical explanations are not overwhelming, and it has a kind of tutorial in R too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ha, That's actually the book I used to learn R. Really good book. To answer your question: I ran the code above with 34 variables and 500 trees. When it completed running. Upon each iteration the code above captures the confusion matrix and stores the accuracy value into lstAccuracy. I converted lstAccuracy into a matrix used to find the highest accuracy variable. This essentially tells me that the best performing model had 4 variables and 14 trees. Not sure if linking to pastbin is ok, but [here is the code for the first model](http://pastebin.com/7eAbNnH0).

Comment: Indeed it is a great book. Ok, more or less understood what you did. I don't think it is a good way. The point of randomForest is that it reduces the variance of the model by averaging many trees. To set the number of trees, you should plot the accuracy versus number of trees, and look for the area in which it gets flat, i.e. adding more trees does not add to accuracy. Anyway, accuracy might not be the best measure, in particularly if your classes are not well balanced. It would be better if you used AUC, or binomial deviance [cont'd]

Comment: Then, for mtry, you select just the best model. Since it usually takes a long time to fit the model, it is usually ok to fix the number of trees first, and then look for the best mtry. But anyway, look for it at the book. I've just got through it quickly, and it is only a few pages, and very clear. Good luck.